# is it posible to use same SqlProfileProvider for two web project?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sqlprofileprovider

I have an asp.net web project which uses a SqlProfileProvider for membership structure,i am calling that project **A** .

Can i use that membership from another asp.net project, project **B** ?

I've tried same connectionstring on project **B**, but i am getting LoginError with asp.net Login control.

But if i try call a member with code on project **B**, as follows;

***MembershipUser oneUser = Membership.GetUser("a user name from project A");***

it works. and it shows me that connectionstrings and other membership params work on B.

But if i use standart Login control on a page, it falls to LoginError method.

thanks in advance for all comments.

**EDIT**:

solved by custom web control..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason it should not work. As you have pointed out that when you are using .net framework, you are able to work against the same membership DB but it is only Login control that is failing. May be some config is missing in Login control. Try to work on that.

Or would it be easy to build your control and don't use built it login control?

Comment: yes Pradeep, u are right. at that moment i am working my own control. but i wonder why the standard login control fails, may be i should check the web.config,as you say..